# Легковесный асинхронный сервис сообщений на джаве

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Вопрос больше по архитектуре, чем по программированию. Мне нужно написать сервис нотификаций, который принимает сообщения по `REST`-апи и делает из них джобы, которые кладет в очередь джобов. Каждый такой джоб надо выполнить. Если он выполняется успешно, джоб удаляется из очереди, а клиенту возвращается сообщение об успехе. Если джоб не выполнился, он помещается во вторую очередь повторных попыток. Количество попыток не больше трех. Оба действия надо логировать. Нужно предусмотреть несколько способов выполнения джоба.

Как это проще всего реализовать? Брокеры сообщения типа RabbitMQ и ActiveMQ это оверкилл. Есть библиотеки, которые создают легковесный брокер в памяти?

Нагрузка на сервис не будет высокой.

Сервис должен быть асинхронным.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону Томкат, там вроде бы это все просто делается внутри. Если я правильно помню.

Comment: @Dred, у меня приложение на спрингбуте испольует томкат по умолчанию. Что именно в нем можно найти?

Comment: а сообщения должны сохранятся между перезапусками приложения?

Comment: Spring WebFlux + Spring Integration

Comment: Сообщения сохраняться не должны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд здесь всё зависит от того, должны ли джобы сохраняться между перезапусками приложения. В любом случае можно использовать простой Thread Pool, создавая его через класс Executors. Сделать один такой пул на уровне приложения и посылать туда все задачи. Это будет асинхронно и без фреймворков.

**1) Если джобы должны сохраняться.**

Можно завести табличку в базе, в которую перед запуском джоба писать информацию о нём (ID, ТИП, СТАТУС, НЕОБХОДИМАЯ ДЛЯ ЗАПУСКА ИНФОРМАЦИЯ). Тогда после запуска приложения можно будет прочитать все джобы со статусом не FINISHED и закинуть в пул для выполнения. При завершении выполнения проставлять статус FINISHED и отправлять нотификацию пользователю.

**2) Если джобы не должны сохраняться.**

Просто закидываем все джобы в пул и посылаем нотификацию по завершении.

Повторные попытки можно разрешить с помощью второго пула, либо при помощи создания нового джоба при провале предыдущего и закидывания в тот же пул. Счётчик попыток можно хранить в той же базе, ну или в объекте джоба в памяти.

Comment: Да, джобы должны сохраняться. Первый пункт похож на реализацию своей очереди сообщений. Не существует ли минималистичной MQ, написанной по стандарту JMS?

Comment: Я пользовался только рэббитом. Насчёт более легковесных не могу подсказать, к сожалению.

Answer (score 0):

В помощь : [ExecutorServices](https://habr.com/ru/post/116363/) и собственно [CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture), на методы для повторения [@Retryable](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) - механизм. я думаю этого будет достаточно.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
</dependency>
```